# Using Fubini's theorem find the value of sine integral

Tags: measure-theory

Using the fact that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}dx = \frac{1}{t}$, for $t >0$ and from Fubini's theorem conclude that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{sinx}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Any hints would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x,t) = e^{-tx} \sin t$ over $(0,\infty) \times (0,n)$. We have no trouble using Fubini here.

To get $\int \left( \int e^{-tx} \sin t \, dt\right) dx$, apply integration by parts twice to get the inner integral (you should be familiar with this method).